# How to get rows as array of JSON object instead of array of array in MySQL X DevAPI select query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json, mysql-x-devapi

I am using [`MySQL X DevAPI`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/) for relational tables in MySQL.

```js
// Working with Relational Tables
var mysqlx = require('@mysql/xdevapi');
var myTable;

// Connect to server using a connection URL
mysqlx
  .getSession({
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 33060
  })
  .then(function (session) {
    // Accessing an existing table
    myTable = session.getSchema('test').getTable('my_table');

    // Insert SQL Table data
    return myTable
      .insert(['name', 'birthday', 'age'])
      .values(['Laurie', '2000-5-27', 19])
      .execute()
  })
  .then(function () {
    // Find a row in the SQL Table
    let columns = ['name', 'birthday']
    return myTable
        .select(columns)
        .where('name like :name && age < :age)')
        .bind('name', 'L%')
        .bind('age', 30)
        .execute();
  })
  .then(function (myResult) {
    let rows = myResult.fetchAll() // this is array of array
    let columns = ['name', 'birthday']
    rows = rows.map((row) => columns.reduce((a, column, index) => Object.assign(a, { [column]: row[index] }), {}))
    console.log(rows); // this is array of JSON object which is usefull for WEB API reposnse.
  });
```

In this code I have to convert array of arrays into array of json object all the time

```js
function (myResult) {
    let rows = myResult.fetchAll() // this is array of array
    let columns = ['name', 'birthday']
    rows = rows.map((row) => columns.reduce((a, column, index) => Object.assign(a, { [column]: row[index] }), {}))
    console.log(rows); // this is array of JSON object which is usefull for WEB API reposnse.
  }
```

X Dev API is good library so there would be some good way to get results in [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format directly.

What are the ways to get rows in JSON format in `MySQL X DevAPI`?

Answer (score 0):

In table mode, you either need to that or you can use something like the [`JSON_OBJECT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object) function and then flat the resulting array.

```
let columns = ['name', 'birthday']
let keyValuePairs = columns.map(c => `"${c}", ${c}`)

const res = await table.select(`JSON_OBJECT(${keyValuePairs})`)
  // ...
  .execute()

const rows = res.fetchAll() 

console.log(rows.flat()) // this is now an array of JSON objects
```

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js